# Casting .resx classes to obtain ResourceSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, casting

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist with data pulled from a .resx file. Instead of having 5 different functions I'd like to be able to pass in the name of the .resx file and cast it somehow so I can retrieve it using GetReourceSet.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
protected void populateCountryPickList(DropDownList whatDropDownList)
{
    ResourceSet rs = Resources.CountryPickList.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
    whatDropDownList.DataSource = rs;
    whatDropDownList.DataTextField = "Value";
    whatDropDownList.DataValueField = "Key";
    whatDropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

In the example above I have a .resx file named CountryPickList.resx so its just a matter of using the .resx name to retrieve the ResourceSet using GetResourceSet...

What I would like to be able to do is figure out how I can pass in a string to my function with the name of the .resx and obtain the same results.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

cheers,

rise4peace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResourceManager` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx) that takes the name of a `resources` file.

You can therefore write the following code:

```
ResourceSet rs = new ResourceManager(whatDropDownList.Name, GetType().Assembly)
                     .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
```

---

**EDIT**: In ASP.Net, it's not quite the same.  You can view the generated source code (`.designer.cs`) for one of your resource files and look at the implementation of the static `ResourceManager` property.

It looks like this:

```
ResourceManager temp = new ResourceManager("Resources.Resource1", Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
```

Comment: Here's the function:

    protected void populateDropDownList(DropDownList whatDropDownList, string whatResourceName)
    {
        ResourceSet rs = new ResourceManager(whatResourceName, GetType().Assembly).GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
        whatDropDownList.DataSource = rs;
        whatDropDownList.DataTextField = "Value";
        whatDropDownList.DataValueField = "Key";
        whatDropDownList.DataBind();
    }

If I have a .resx file named statelist.resx in the App_GlobalResources. I assume I can pass just statelist to this function?